# Who is the best striker (best goals/appearances ratio) with 25/50/100+ national caps?

Tags: football, trivia, statistics

Zlatan Ibrahimovic recently had his 50 goals milestone (also a national record for Sweden) prior to with 100 appearance for the team. With 50 goals in 100 games he's averaging a goal in every second game which is as far as I can tell a great ratio, making him one of the most prominent strikers of modern football.

Which brings me to my question, *who is the "best" striker in football history, judging by the goals/appearances ratio*? In order to avoid outliers with only a few caps, I chose to focus on veteran strikers who have played at least 25/50/100 games for their national team.

Comment: Just to clarify, best goal/appearance ratio for National team games *only*, right?

Comment: A cap limit is needed, but limiting to 100+ caps removes quite a few veterans from previous eras, like Pelé, Gerd Müller, Ferenc Puskás and Sándor Kocsis, who are more than statistical outliers. So good question, but don't expect a definitive answer to the "best" in history.

Comment: @Fillet agreed, I had to put a limit and went with 100 as it's relevant for Zlatan's accomplishment. It would be interesting to check that stat with 50 caps as well, I agree.

Comment: @posdef Min. 25 games, [Poul Nielsen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poul_Nielsen) 1.37; Min 50 games, [Ferenc Puskás](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferenc_Pusk%C3%A1s) 0.99...

Comment: @posdef - Will do. Please update your question to ask about 25 game minimum, and 50 game minimum as well so the additional information in my answer will be related to  your question :-)

Comment: According to that wikipedia table it is not possible to reply to the question. E.G: it can be a player from Iran with 108 goal in 108 caps (ratio = 1) or a brazialian with 76 goal in 100 caps (ratio = 0.76)...

Comment: What I have just realized about this Wiki, is that it is *most goals* for each country, not *highest ratio*! My answer will need to be revised because the question asks for best goal ratio, which this Wiki does not necessarily tell us. E.g., Klose has the most goals for Germany, but Gerd Muller actually has a *better ratio*...

Comment: I thought that it might be interesting to ask the same questions about goals scored at the club level: http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5761/which-soccer-players-have-more-goals-than-caps-at-the-club-level  (Although I do not think there will be many players who managed something like that.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this answer will probably need occasional updates, I have made it [community wiki](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/community-wiki/info).

The post is compiled from these sources:<sup>1</sup>

- [More goals than caps](http://www.fifa.com/world-match-centre/news/newsid/106/577/9/index.html) at fifa.com ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/http://www.fifa.com/world-match-centre/news/newsid/106/577/9/index.html))
- [List of footballers with 50 or more international goals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_footballers_with_50_or_more_international_goals) at Wikipedia. (Link to an [older revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_footballers_with_50_or_more_international_goals&oldid=630729397), around the time when the first version of this posts was compiled.)
- Wikipedia articles about individual players.

Below is the list of players having more goals than caps which have played at least 25/50 international games.

**25+ caps**

1. [Poul Nielsen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poul_Nielsen) (Denmark) 1.37 (52 goals in 38 games)
2. [Gunnar Nordahl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunnar_Nordahl) (Sweden) 1.30 (43 goals in 33 games)
3. [Sven Rydell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sven_Rydell) (Sweden) 1.14 (49 goals in 43 games)
4. [Ernest Wilimowski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Wilimowski) (Poland, West Germany) 1.13 (34 goals in 30 games)

**50+ caps**

1. [Sándor Kocsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A1ndor_Kocsis) (Hungary) 1.102 (75 goals in 68 games)
2. [Gerd Müller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerd_M%C3%BCller) (Germany) 1.097 (68 goals in 62 games)

**100+ caps**

According to the sources I cited above, there are no players in this category with an average number of goals above 1. The best goals-per-game ratio of any player with 100+ caps is that of [Ali Daei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali_Daei) (Iran), at 0.74 (109 goals in 148 games).

The players with at least 100 caps and average at least 0.50 can be found in the Wikipedia article: [List of men's footballers with 50 or more international goals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_men%27s_footballers_with_50_or_more_international_goals).

---

[Ferenc Puskás](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferenc_Pusk%C3%A1s) is close to 1 goal per match ratio with 84 goals in 85 matches if we *only count* his appearances for *Hungary.* After emigration he also played in 4 international matches for Spain.

Another near-miss is [Kunishige Kamamoto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunishige_Kamamoto) (Japan) with 75 goals in 76 appearances.

Also [Luis Artime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luis_Artime) (Argentina) was very close to make the above list, with 24 goals in 25 appearances.

---

<sup>1</sup> See also the comments to Nicholas V.'s answer and the links mentioned there.

Comment: I am not sure about the reason, but Godfrey Chitalu is now missing from the list on Wikipedia. Here is a link to [an older revision](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_footballers_with_50_or_more_international_goals&oldid=630729397) where he was still included.

Answer (score 5):

Information on record scorers by country is available on [*Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_top_international_association_football_goal_scorers_by_country).

With the table *sorted by Goal scoring ratio*, the highest goals per international game meeting the minimum national caps is listed below:

### Min. 100 Caps:

- [**Godfrey Chitalu**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godfrey_Chitalu), with a ratio of **0.73** goals per international game played.

### Min. 50 Caps:

- [**Ferenc Puskás**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferenc_Pusk%C3%A1s), with a ratio of **0.99** goals per international game played.

### Min. 25 Caps:

- [**Poul Nielsen**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poul_Nielsen), with a ratio of **1.37** goals per international game played.

---

[image: Screenshot on Wikipedia table used in answering this question.]

---

<sub>Assuming Wikipedia's data is accurate.</sub>

Comment: According to this table is it possible that a player from Iran has scored 108 gol with 108 caps (for example) with a ratio of 1. So I think this table do not reply correctly, mostly for >25 and >50 caps

Comment: Agree with @Ale, except that is it not only possible: According to [wikipedia, Gerd Müller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerd_M%C3%BCller) has scored 68 goals in 62 appearances, so the above list (including only the top scorers by country in terms of total goals) is the wrong source to answer this question.

Comment: That's it! In fact for min 50 caps and min 25 caps the reply is more difficult

Comment: @arne.b, yeah, I've recognized this in the question's comments, I just need some time to get around to revising this answer.

Comment: For example, Sandor Kocsis has 1.10 average from 68 games, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungary_national_football_team#Top_goalscorers).
I think that [this link](http://www.fifa.com/world-match-centre/news/newsid/106/577/9/index.html) might help. (It was given in the Wikipedia article you mentioned in your answer.)

Comment: [This list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_footballers_with_50_or_more_international_goals) seems to help with 100+ caps; since in order  to beat Chitalu's the player would have to score at least 73 goals.

Comment: @Martin - yep. I should have mentioned this on my answer's comments, instead I referenced on the *question's* comments. This is all pretty clear, don't worry. Just need some time to revise the answer =)

Comment: @NicholasV. I have posted another answer, based on some of the links mentioned in my comments here. I see no harm in having two answers. I just wanted to mention this to you - so that you are aware of the other answer in case you start working on revising yours.

Comment: As far as [Puskás](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferenc_Pusk%C3%A1s) is concerned, it should be mentioned that the ratio 0.99 is calculated only from his games for Hungary. After his emigration, he also played 4 games for Spain, but did not score any goals.