# Which female football players have highest goal per game ratio for national team?

Tags: football, trivia, statistics

We have similar question for men: [Who is the best striker (best goals/appearances ratio) with 25/50/100+ national caps?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/5701) So it seems quite natural to ask about women, too.

Which female footballers have the highest goal/matches ratio when playing for the national team? Are there players with more goals than than caps?

To avoid statistical outliers (e.g., a player who only played one match and scored two goals), it seems natural to add some restrictions. For examples, looking at players who have at least 25/50/100 caps. (Similarely as in the linked question.)

Looking at Wikipedia page [List of women's footballers with 100 or more international goals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_women%27s_footballers_with_100_or_more_international_goals) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_women%27s_footballers_with_100_or_more_international_goals&oldid=863660894)) it seems that in the category 100+ there are no players with more goals than caps. Although both [Elisabetta Vignotto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elisabetta_Vignotto) and [Marta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marta_(footballer)) got rather close to 1 goal per match.

Answer (score 1):

According to the same Wikipedia page, you can check out the table, and set the ranking according to "goals per match". This allows you to see that the highest ratio for female players is 0.97, achieved by Julie Fleeting, Marta, and Elisabetta Vignotto. Although, Marta is still a current player and might be able to top that ratio in the coming years.

Abby Wambach is the top scorer with 184 international goals, however she has 256 caps, making her ratio 0.72.